# How to declare array in shell script?

Tags: shell

I am trying to declare an array in my shell script and then have written a for loop to access those array elements into another file. But it is only taking the first element. I've tried the below :

```
raw_cd=(1150 1151)
i=0


for i in "${raw_cd[@]}"
do
  grep -wr  "${raw_cd[@]}" file1.txt  > /opt/tmp/raw.txt
  echo "$i"
done
```

It is taking only the first element 1150 and also giving output as :-

```
file1.txt:|1150|
file1.txt:|1150|
file1.txt:|1150|
```

where am i doing wrong?

Comment: It seems you haven't increased ```i``` or remove ```i=0``` completely

Comment: don't you mean `grep -wr "$i" file1.txt` instead?

Comment: @Amadan but $i would give me the index count, is'nt?

Comment: @Hellious how and where in the code can i do that?

Comment: `> /opt/tmp/raw.txt` overwrites the file each loop. Did you mean to `>> /opt/tmp/raw.txt`?

Comment: @Aviator : POSIX Shell does not have arrays. You would have to go for (i.e.) bash or zsh or ksh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` does not deal with indices, just raw values. Thus,

```
raw_cd=(1150 1151)
for i in "${raw_cd[@]}"
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

will print

```
1150
1151
```

If you want to use indices, you need to produce them yourself:

```
raw_cd=(1150 1151)
for i in $(seq "${#raw_cd[@]}")
do
  echo "$i": "${raw_cd[$i - 1]}"
done
```

will produce

```
1: 1150
2: 1151
```

Even better, you can directly get keys like this, without `seq` (this will work even on associative arrays):

```
raw_cd=(1150 1151)
for i in "${!raw_cd[@]}"
do
  echo "$i": "${raw_cd[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: How can I achieve this by using for loop?

Comment: I don't understand — I just showed you two (EDIT: three) snippets, _each_ of which uses a `for` loop.

Comment: tried it but its not working n giving error.

Comment: If you are getting an error, you should also say what that error is, then maybe I can figure out what is happening. If you don't, the most that I can say is that it works for me — I copy-pasted my output, I didn't invent it.

Comment: Maybe I know what it is — the second snippet might be `zsh`-specific. The first snippet should work in both `bash` and `zsh`

Comment: raw_cd=(1150 1151)
 for i in $(seq "$#raw_cd")
do
grep -wr  "$i" file1.txt  > path/file2.txt
        echo "$i"
done

Comment: I m trying this code but getting error as : 
seq: invalid floating point argument: 0cgc_arr
Try `seq --help' for more information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229442/discussion-between-amadan-and-aviator).

Comment: Yep, I inadvertently used `zsh`. I fixed all examples to work under `bash`.